# Constant-sized vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Does someone know the way to define constant-sized vector?

For example, instead of defining

```
std::vector<int>
```

it will be

```
std::vector<10, int>
```

**It should be completely cross-platformed**. Maybe an open source class?

Comment: Sounds like what you want is [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The std::vector can always grow dynamically, but there are two ways you can allocate an initial size:

This allocates initial size and fills the elements with zeroes:

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
v.size(); //returns 10
```

This allocates an initial size but does not populate the array with zeroes:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(10);
v.size(); //returns 0
```

Comment: if it was a vector of some user defined type that was given a initial size, what would it be initialized to?

Comment: The answers below that say to use std::array should be accepted

Comment: I came here looking for this answer. The question looks a lot like someone looking for an `std::array`, but I for one do not know my size at compile time and do want to just allocate a certain number of elements fixed.

Comment: `vector<int> v(10)` --> *allocates initial size and fills the elements with zeroes* i.e. **allocates the space and constructs the object.** while `v.reserve(10)` --> *allocates an initial size but does not populate the array with zeroes.* i.e. **just allocates the space but does not construct the object** -- very important!

Answer (score 75):

There is no way to define a constant size vector. If you know the size at compile time, you could use C++11's [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) aggregate.

```
#include <array>

std::array<int, 10> a;
```

If you don't have the relevant C++11 support, you could use the TR1 version:

```
#include <tr1/array>

std::tr1::array<int, 10> a;
```

or [boost::array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/array.html), as has been suggested in other answers.

Comment: Although be aware that `array` is different from `vector` in that the data is contained inside the object. For 10 ints you may never notice the difference, but for large arrays you might (for example) notice that they do not have `O(1)` `swap`, whereas large vectors do.

Comment: Also be aware that an array doesn't have a concept of `size` vs `capacity` like vector does. In an array `size` == `max_size`. That is, you can't create an array of size 10 (ie: space for 10 possible elements), but populate only 5 and expect `size` to return 5.

Comment: Also note that std::array does not cast to a generic run time size. If you want to pass different sized arrays to a function, you would have to pass in both the data() and size()

Comment: @SteveLorimer *"... but for large arrays you might (for example) notice that they do not have O(1) swap, whereas large vectors do."* --
could you please share resources/references that I can look into to understand more about this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Milan for a vector you swap just the pointer to the underlying array, whereas unless the array is allocated on the heap (thereby allowing you to swap just the pointer to the array) you have to move all the elements. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26312602/955273

Comment: @SteveLorimer Thanks for further clarification. But, I'm still super confused: if I initialize a vector like this: `std::vector<int> vec1 = {1, 2, 3}`, it will/should be allocated on the stack only, right? It will get allocated on the heap, only if I initialize it like this: `std::vector<int> *vec2 = new std::vector<int>({1, 2, 3})`, isn't it? Please correct me if I'm mistaken. Thanks again!

Comment: @Milan yes and no - the vector object itself will be stored on the stack, but *internally* it has dynamic storage which is allocated on the heap. The reason for this is that a vector does not have a fixed number of items it can store; you can change the number of elements at run time. As the number of items in the vector increases it may need to allocate a new larger array for its internal storage (dynamically/"on the heap"). So when you `swap` 2 vectors, it's the pointers to these internal arrays which get swapped

Comment: @SteveLorimer Thank you so much for such a quick response and detailed explanation. I appreciate that. Sorry, but the further question (hopefully the last one): If the vector internally has dynamic storage then does it ever/even make any sense to initialize the vector object itself on the heap using `new`? (I think initializing using the smart pointers is a whole different matter here, correct?)

Comment: @Milan in general no, I would not see much sense in creating the vector itself on the heap, unless you wanted to differentiate between a "null" vector and an empty vector... but for that you would probably be better served using `std::optional`

Comment: Isn't std::array holding it's data bufer on the stack? As opposed to it allocating and constructing on the heap when it is constructed itself.

Answer (score 22):

This is an old question but if someone just needs **constant-size indexed container with size defined at runtime**, I like to use *unique_ptr*:

```
// c++14
auto constantContainer = std::make_unique<YourType []> ( size );

// c++11
std::unique_ptr<YourType[]> constantContainer {new YourType[ size ]};


// Access
constantContainer[ i ]
```

Comment: Can you add a solution for C++11?  Also, will a unique pointer have the same performance as a vector?

Comment: Yes, both have just plain buffer underneath.

Comment: Umm, this would be non-copyable,, wouldn't it?

Comment: This is the only real answer to this question, if we don't want to use custom classes (by @ Marcel ) or external libraries ( by @ steve-lorimer ). I am surprised C++ does not have it.

Answer (score 18):

If you want a fixed compile-time specified size (ala `std::array<T, N>`), but you want to be able to populate the vector with varying numbers of elements between `0` and `N`, then a good option is [`eastl::fixed_vector`](https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/include/EASTL/fixed_vector.h).

**std::vector:**

The size of a `std::vector` is dynamic - it will allocate required storage dynamically, and you cannot limit the size and enforce an error.

You can however `reserve` a certain size, and then add elements up that size before it needs to allocate new storage.

`vector.size()` is initially 0, and increases as you add elementss

**std::array:**

The size of a `std::array` is a compile-time constant - it will allocate required storage statically, and you cannot change the size.

`array.size()` is always the size of the array, and is equal to `array.max_size()`

**eastl::fixed_vector:**

The size of an `eastl::fixed_vector` can be either static or dynamic.

It will allocate a certain number of elements initially, and then if you allow dynamic growth, will allocate dynamically if required.

For the purpose you originally asked for, you can disable growth (via `bEnableOverflow` in the template instantiation below)

`fixed_vector.size()` is initially 0, and increases as you add elements.

```
template<typename T, 
         size_t nodeCount, 
         bool bEnableOverflow = true, 
         typename OverflowAllocator = 
                      typename eastl::type_select<bEnableOverflow,
                                                  EASTLAllocatorType, 
                                                  EASTLDummyAllocatorType>::type>
class fixed_vector;
```

Simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include "EASTL/fixed_vector.h"

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(10);
    std::cout << "size=" << v.size() << " capacity=" << v.capacity() << '\n';

    std::array<int, 10> a;
    std::cout << "size=" << a.size() << " capacity=" << a.max_size() << '\n';

    eastl::fixed_vector<int, 10, false> fv;
    std::cout << "size=" << fv.size() << " capacity=" << fv.capacity() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
size=0 capacity=10
size=10 capacity=10
size=0 capacity=10
```

Note that the size of `array` is 10, whereas `vector` and `fixed_vector` are 0

Answer (score 13):

Use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)

For better readability you can make typedef:

```
typedef std::array<int, 10> MyIntArray;
```

Comment: Of course, since we're writing C++11, we'd write `using MyIntArray = std::array<int, 10>;`.

Comment: That is assuming the size is known at compile time.

Answer (score 11):

A `std::vector` is a dynamic container, there is no mechanism to restrict its growth. To allocate an initial size:

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
```

C++11 has a [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) that would be more appropriate:

```
std::array<int, 10> my_array;
```

If your compiler does not support C++11 consider using [`boost::array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/array.html):

```
boost::array<int, 10> my_array;
```

Answer (score 4):

This ----> `std::vector<10, int>` is invalid and causes error. But the new C++ standard has introduced a new class; the std::array. You can declare an array like this:

```
std::array<int, 5> arr; // declares a new array that holds 5 ints
std::array<int, 5> arr2(arr); // arr2 is equal to arr
std::array<int, 5> arr3 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // arr3 holds 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

The `std::array` has constant size and supports `iterator/const_iterator/reverse_iterator/const_reverse_iterator`. You can find more about this class at http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/array/.

Answer (score 3):

Improving the answer from Pari 
**I have been using the following class for many years** in number crunching applications:

```cpp
inline void nodeleter(void*) {}

/// Array of T with ownership. Like \see std::unique_ptr<T[]> but with size tracking.
/// @tparam T Element type.
template <typename T>
class unique_array : public std::unique_ptr<T[],void (*)(void*)>
{   size_t Size;
private:
    typedef std::unique_ptr<T[],void (*)(void*)> base;
protected:
    unique_array(T* ptr, size_t size, void (*deleter)(void*)) noexcept : base(ptr, deleter), Size(size) {}
    void reset(T* ptr, size_t size) noexcept { base::reset(ptr); Size = size; }
public:
    constexpr unique_array() noexcept : base(nullptr, operator delete[]), Size(0) {}
    explicit unique_array(size_t size) : base(new T[size], operator delete[]), Size(size) {}
    template <size_t N> unique_array(T(&arr)[N]) : base(arr, &nodeleter), Size(N) {}
    unique_array(unique_array<T>&& r) : base(move(r)), Size(r.Size) { r.Size = 0; }
    void reset(size_t size = 0) { base::reset(size ? new T[size] : nullptr); Size = size; }
    void swap(unique_array<T>&& other) noexcept { base::swap(other); std::swap(Size, other.Size); }
    void assign(const unique_array<T>& r) const { assert(Size == r.Size); std::copy(r.begin(), r.end(), begin()); }
    const unique_array<T>& operator =(const unique_array<T>& r) const { assign(r); return *this; }
    size_t size() const noexcept { return Size; }
    T* begin() const noexcept { return base::get(); }
    T* end() const noexcept { return begin() + Size; }
    T& operator[](size_t i) const { assert(i < Size); return base::operator[](i); }
    unique_array<T> slice(size_t start, size_t count) const noexcept
    {   assert(start + count <= Size); return unique_array<T>(begin() + start, count, &nodeleter); }
};
```

- **Assignment is possible** but this *must not change the size* (although it would be easy to implement).
- You may **change the size by calling `reset`**, but as the name suggests this discards any data.
- **Move semantics** are supported.
- `const` instances do not make their content `const`. Only the *storage* cannot be changed.
- It has also limited **support for slices** not owned by the instance. But they have not lifetime management. You need to care about dangling references yourself.
- There are some features missing to be fully compatible to the C++ `Container` requirement, first of all the typedefs. I never needed them so far.
- It is easy to extend this type for numeric types and add further vector operations. But there is no straight forward automatism since at least `std::is_arithmetic<std::complex<double>>::value` is false.

Answer (score 1):

I found that `std::vector` actually has `max_size()` member and there is a customization point in the std library to tune vector behavior accordingly. So I just tuned `std::vector` to apply a cap on `max_size()` and narrow `size_type`.
Compiles with c++11 and newer

- -Werror -Wextra

  - gcc >= 4.9.0
  - clang >= 3.3
- /W4 /WX /external:anglebrackets /external:W3

  - MSVC >= 19.20

Most of the code is meaningless boilerplate you can easily cut off if you don't need to support cross platform compilation and/or older versions of c++, the only real logic is inside of `Allocator` members. Use any allocator and vector types that are compatible with the standard and you can have a caped vector. `using CapedVector = Caped<uint16_t>::Vector<char>;` You can drop `Vector` and just use `template <class T> using CapedVector = std::vector<T, Caped<uint16_t>::Allocator<std::allocator<T>>>` if you don't need to narrow `size_type`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

#if __cpp_constexpr >= 201603L
// c++17
#define NODISCARD [[nodiscard]]
#else
#define NODISCARD
#endif

#if __cpp_constexpr > 200704L
// c++14
#define CONSTEXPR constexpr
#else
#define CONSTEXPR
#endif

#ifndef __cpp_concepts
template <class Size, Size maxSize = std::numeric_limits<Size>::max(), class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<Size>::value>::type>
#elif defined CONSTEXPR
template <class Size, Size maxSize = std::numeric_limits<Size>::max(), class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned_v<Size>>>
#else
template <class Size, Size maxSize = std::numeric_limits<Size>::max()> requires(std::is_unsigned_v<Size>)
#endif
struct Caped
{
    using size_type = Size;
    template <class A>
    struct Allocator : A
    {
        using value_type = typename std::allocator_traits<A>::value_type;
        using pointer = typename std::allocator_traits<A>::pointer;
        using const_pointer = typename std::allocator_traits<A>::const_pointer;
        using void_pointer = typename std::allocator_traits<A>::void_pointer;
        using const_void_pointer = typename std::allocator_traits<A>::const_void_pointer;
        using difference_type = typename std::allocator_traits<A>::difference_type;
        using propagate_on_container_copy_assignment = typename std::allocator_traits<A>::propagate_on_container_copy_assignment;
        using propagate_on_container_move_assignment = typename std::allocator_traits<A>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment;
        using propagate_on_container_swap = typename std::allocator_traits<A>::propagate_on_container_swap;
#ifdef __cpp_lib_allocator_traits_is_always_equal
        using is_always_equal = typename std::allocator_traits<A>::is_always_equal;
#endif
        using A::A;

        using size_type = Caped::size_type;

        template <class U>
        struct rebind
        {
            using other = Allocator<typename std::allocator_traits<A>::template rebind_alloc<U>>;
        };
        CONSTEXPR size_type max_size() const noexcept
        {
            using BaseSize = typename std::allocator_traits<A>::size_type;
            static_assert(sizeof(BaseSize) >= sizeof(size_type), "allocator size_type must be bigger than cap type");
            return static_cast<size_type>(std::min<BaseSize>(maxSize, std::allocator_traits<A>::max_size(*this)));
        }
        NODISCARD CONSTEXPR pointer allocate(std::size_t n)
        {
            return n <= max_size() ? std::allocator_traits<A>::allocate(*this, n) : throw std::bad_array_new_length();
        }
#ifdef __cpp_lib_allocate_at_least
        NODISCARD constexpr pointer allocate_at_least(std::size_t n)
        {            
            return n <= max_size() ? std::allocator_traits<A>::allocate_at_least(*this, n) : throw std::bad_array_new_length();
        }
#endif
    };

    template<class T, template <class, class> class V = std::vector, class A = std::allocator<T>>
    struct Vector : V<T, Allocator<A>>
    {
        using Base = V<T, Allocator<A>>;
        using typename Base::value_type;
        using typename Base::allocator_type;
        using typename Base::difference_type;
        using typename Base::reference;
        using typename Base::const_reference;
        using typename Base::pointer;
        using typename Base::const_pointer;
        using typename Base::iterator;
        using typename Base::const_iterator;
        using typename Base::reverse_iterator;
        using typename Base::const_reverse_iterator;
        using Base::Base;
        using Base::assign;
        using Base::insert;

        using size_type = typename allocator_type::size_type;

        CONSTEXPR Vector(size_type count, const T& value, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type()) : Base(count, value, alloc){}
#if _MSVC_LANG <= 201402L
        CONSTEXPR explicit Vector(size_type count) : Base(count) {};
        CONSTEXPR explicit Vector(size_type count, const allocator_type& alloc) : Base(count, alloc){}
#else
        CONSTEXPR explicit Vector(size_type count, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type()) : V(count, alloc){}
#endif
        CONSTEXPR void assign(size_type count, const T& value) { Base::assign(count, value); }
        CONSTEXPR reference at(size_type pos) { return Base::at(pos); }
        CONSTEXPR const_reference at(size_type pos) const { return Base::at(pos); }
        CONSTEXPR reference operator[](size_type pos) { return Base::operator [](pos); };
        CONSTEXPR const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const { return Base::operator [](pos); };
        CONSTEXPR size_type size() const noexcept { return static_cast<size_type>(Base::size()); }
        CONSTEXPR size_type max_size() const noexcept { return static_cast<size_type>(Base::max_size()); }
        CONSTEXPR size_type capacity() const noexcept { return static_cast<size_type>(Base::capacity()); }
        CONSTEXPR iterator insert(const_iterator pos, size_type count, const T& value) { return Base::insert(pos, count, value); };
        CONSTEXPR void resize(size_type count) { Base::resize(count); };
        CONSTEXPR void resize(size_type count, const value_type& value) { Base::resize(count, value); };
    };
};
```

[godbolt snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/j1MYb3sx6)

Answer (score 1):

Jason Turner shares **simple_stack_vector** on his github

I modified ::resize () method as it was causing some issue:

```
constexpr void resize ( const size_type new_size )
{
    if ( new_size <= size_ )
    {
        size_ = new_size;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( new_size > Capacity )
        {
            // throw std::length_error("resize would exceed static capacity");
        }
        else
        {
            size_ = new_size;
        }
    }
}
```

And the original code

https://github.com/lefticus/tools/blob/main/include/lefticus/tools/simple_stack_vector.hpp

```
#ifndef LEFTICUS_TOOLS_SIMPLE_STACK_VECTOR_HPP
#define LEFTICUS_TOOLS_SIMPLE_STACK_VECTOR_HPP

#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

namespace lefticus::tools {


// changes from std::vector
//  * capacity if fixed at compile-time
//  * it never allocates
//  * items must be default constructible
//  * items are never destroyed until the entire stack_vector
//    is destroyed.
//  * iterators are never invalidated
//  * capacity() and max_size() are now static functions
//  * should be fully C++17 usable within constexpr
template<typename Contained, std::size_t Capacity> struct simple_stack_vector
{
  using value_type = Contained;
  using data_type = std::array<value_type, Capacity>;
  using size_type = typename data_type::size_type;
  using difference_type = typename data_type::difference_type;
  using reference = value_type &;
  using const_reference = const value_type &;

  static_assert(std::is_default_constructible_v<Contained>);

  using iterator = typename data_type::iterator;
  using const_iterator = typename data_type::const_iterator;
  using reverse_iterator = typename data_type::reverse_iterator;
  using const_reverse_iterator = typename data_type::const_reverse_iterator;

  constexpr simple_stack_vector() = default;
  constexpr explicit simple_stack_vector(std::initializer_list<value_type> values)
  {
    for (const auto &value : values) { push_back(value); }
  }

  template<typename OtherContained, std::size_t OtherSize>
  constexpr explicit simple_stack_vector(const simple_stack_vector<OtherContained, OtherSize> &other)
  {
    for (const auto &value : other) { push_back(Contained{ value }); }
  }

  template<typename Type> constexpr explicit simple_stack_vector(const std::vector<Type> &values)
  {
    for (const auto &value : values) { push_back(Contained{ value }); }
  }

  template<typename Itr> constexpr simple_stack_vector(Itr begin, Itr end)
  {
    while (begin != end) {
      push_back(*begin);
      ++begin;
    }
  }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr iterator begin() noexcept { return data_.begin(); }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept { return data_.cbegin(); }
  [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept { return data_.cbegin(); }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr iterator end() noexcept
  {
    return std::next(data_.begin(), static_cast<difference_type>(size_));
  }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_iterator end() const noexcept
  {
    return std::next(data_.cbegin(), static_cast<difference_type>(size_));
  }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr value_type &front() noexcept { return data_.front(); }
  [[nodiscard]] constexpr const value_type &front() const noexcept { return data_.front(); }
  [[nodiscard]] constexpr value_type &back() noexcept { return data_.back(); }
  [[nodiscard]] constexpr const value_type &back() const noexcept { return data_.back(); }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_iterator cend() const noexcept { return end(); }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr reverse_iterator rbegin() noexcept
  {
    return std::next(data_.rbegin(), static_cast<difference_type>(Capacity - size_));
  }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const noexcept
  {
    return std::next(data_.crbegin(), static_cast<difference_type>(Capacity - size_));
  }
  [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const noexcept { return rbegin(); }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr bool empty() const noexcept { return size_ == 0; }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr reverse_iterator rend() noexcept { return data_.rend(); }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_reverse_iterator rend() const noexcept { return data_.crend(); }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_reverse_iterator crend() const noexcept { return data_.crend(); }

  template<typename Value> constexpr value_type &push_back(Value &&value)
  {
    if (size_ == Capacity) { throw std::length_error("push_back would exceed static capacity"); }
    data_[size_] = std::forward<Value>(value);
    return data_[size_++];
  }

  template<typename... Param> constexpr value_type &emplace_back(Param &&...param)
  {
    if (size_ == Capacity) { throw std::length_error("emplace_back would exceed static capacity"); }
    data_[size_] = value_type{ std::forward<Param>(param)... };
    return data_[size_++];
  }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr value_type &operator[](const std::size_t idx) noexcept { return data_[idx]; }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr const value_type &operator[](const std::size_t idx) const noexcept { return data_[idx]; }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr value_type &at(const std::size_t idx)
  {
    if (idx > size_) { throw std::out_of_range("index past end of stack_vector"); }
    return data_[idx];
  }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr const value_type &at(const std::size_t idx) const
  {
    if (idx > size_) { throw std::out_of_range("index past end of stack_vector"); }
    return data_[idx];
  }

  // resets the size to 0, but does not destroy any existing objects
  constexpr void clear() { size_ = 0; }


  // cppcheck-suppress functionStatic
  constexpr void reserve(size_type new_capacity)
  {
    if (new_capacity > Capacity) { throw std::length_error("new capacity would exceed max_size for stack_vector"); }
  }

  // cppcheck-suppress functionStatic
  [[nodiscard]] constexpr static size_type capacity() noexcept { return Capacity; }

  // cppcheck-suppress functionStatic
  [[nodiscard]] constexpr static size_type max_size() noexcept { return Capacity; }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr size_type size() const noexcept { return size_; }


  constexpr void resize(const size_type new_size)
  {
    if (new_size <= size_) {
      size_ = new_size;
    } else {
      if (new_size > Capacity) {
        throw std::length_error("resize would exceed static capacity");
      } else {
        auto old_end = end();
        size_ = new_size;
        auto new_end = end();
        while (old_end != new_end) {
          *old_end = data_type{};
          ++old_end;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  constexpr void pop_back() noexcept { --size_; }

  // cppcheck-suppress functionStatic
  constexpr void shrink_to_fit() noexcept
  {
    // nothing to do here
  }


private:
  // default initializing to make it more C++17 friendly
  data_type data_{};
  size_type size_{};
};


template<typename Contained, std::size_t LHSSize, std::size_t RHSSize>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr bool operator==(const simple_stack_vector<Contained, LHSSize> &lhs,
  const simple_stack_vector<Contained, RHSSize> &rhs)
{
  if (lhs.size() == rhs.size()) {
    for (std::size_t idx = 0; idx < lhs.size(); ++idx) {
      if (lhs[idx] != rhs[idx]) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

}// namespace lefticus::tools


#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a reason to want this: someone else's code that used std::vector, plus not wanting to use dynamic allocation for this data. std::array didn't work for me.  I used Allocator to do it.

Templated allocator:

```
template<class Tp>
struct FixedVectorAllocator
{
  typedef Tp value_type;
  int mCount;
  Tp *mData;
  FixedVectorAllocator() = delete;

  template<class T>
  FixedVectorAllocator (const FixedVectorAllocator<T>&) {}

  /* Constructor takes a count and a pre-existing buffer
  template<class T>
  FixedVectorAllocator (int count, T* buffer)
  {
    mCount = count;
    mData = buffer;
  };
 
  Tp* allocate(std::size_t n)
  {
    if (n == mCount)
      {
        Tp* p = mData;
      std::cout << "allocating " << n << " records @ " << p << " from Buffer!\n";
        return mData;
      }
    else
      {
      return nullptr; /* If you trust your code never to call this */
      n *= sizeof(Tp);
      Tp* p = (Tp*) (::operator new(n));
      std::cout << "allocating " << n << " bytes @ " << p << '\n';
        return p;
      }
  }
 
  void deallocate(Tp* p, std::size_t n)
  {
    if (p == mData)
    {
      std::cout << "No deallocation here!\n";
    }
    else {
      std::cout << "deallocating " << n * sizeof *p << " bytes @ " << p << " " << mCount << "\n\n";
      ::operator delete(p);
    }
  }
};

/* Didn't pay any attention to these, never came up. */

    template<class T, class U>
    bool operator==(const FixedVectorAllocator<T>&, const FixedVectorAllocator<U>&) { return true; }
    template<class T, class U>
    bool operator!=(const FixedVectorAllocator<T>&, const FixedVectorAllocator<U>&) { return false; }

/* Define an array of data and an allocator using it:
int myIntegers[30];

static FixedVectorAllocator<int> integers(30,myIntegers);

/* Define the std::vector using the fixed vector */
  std::vector<int,FixedVectorAllocator<int>> myVector(30,integers);

/* Now, use the vector */
DoSomethingWithAVector (myVector);
```

This was helpful for me; the consuming code required a vector, and in the
situation in which I was using it, the consuming code never tries to resize the vector.

My recollection is that reserve() which gets called during construction doesn't specify getting the exact number, but >=, but that in practice it's exact.  I have test suites to notice if something changes, though I don't expect it to.

Pardon any typos above.

Comment: Looks like a missing closing comment */

Answer (score 0):

Since C++20 there's **spans**. Which've been introduced exactly to modify a view of a sequence container. Presume you got the value for `number` (*EVEN AT RUNTIME*). Then, after initializing some vector `vec<T>` with appropriate ctor (see your fave STD refs), you can use `std::span` named above as follows:

```
/*some initializing process  of vec<T> here...*/
std::span<T> fixedSizeVec{vec};
/*use of fixedSizeVec as alias of array variable*/
```

Subscript operators overloaded, and range-based for-loops are available of course, too, so you just use that `fixed-sizeVector` in the remainder of your code as alias for original `vec`, which behaves exectly as fixes-size array, since you can't trigger any object-adding/creating/deleting member function by `std::span`.