# Std Container of varying number of elements but no dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, containers, std, c++20, stdvector

Not quite the same as [Stack-Overflow Question: Constant Size Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134497/constant-sized-vector).

I need a container for size_t with the following properties:

1. push_back, contains, find, and erase; as for vector<size_t>
2. prescribed fixed memory footprint (I know the maximum number of elements at compile time as a constexpr).

The array class doesn't do the trick because array always contains the given number of elements. So I need a container that distinguishes between the memory it reserves and the items that it actually contains yet.

Who knows a suitable container in the c++2020 standard?

Comment: Use [boost static vector](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost/container/static_vector.html).

Comment: i dont think it exists out of the box, but you can use `std::vector` with custom allocator. Or wrap an `std::array<char,n*sizeof(T)>` and then use its memory to store the elements.

Comment: wait a sec... the elements are `size_t` ? and no dynamic allocation? Then there is almost no difference between having the element and having only the memory ready to place an element. Keep it simple and use `std::array`

Comment: Use a custom allocator with `std::vector`.

Comment: how is it not the same as the liked question? Just use `reserve`. What's the problem with that?

Comment: reserve uses "new" once. This is incompatible with certain targets. @Jeffrey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of vector is:

```
template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> class vector;
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Notice the `Allocator` part. :-)

So, if you were, say, in a high-code-maturity environment with a linter that forbids the use of `new`, you could provide an allocator that allocates from a fixed static pool. This allocator could enforce the needed constraints.